# How to Inject Angular2 Http service into es6/7 Class?

Tags: javascript, angular, babeljs

If I use es6/7 (babel - stage 1) instead of TypeScript, how are services, and specifically Http, injected?

Here's my component JS:

```
import {Component, Inject, View, CORE_DIRECTIVES, ViewEncapsulation} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'login'
})
@View({
  templateUrl: './components/login/login.html',
  styleUrls: ['components/login/login.css'],
  directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated
})
export class Login {
  constructor(@Inject(Http) http) {
    console.log('http', http);
  }

  authenticate(username, password) {
    // this.http.get('/login');
  }
}
```

I have tried:

```
export class Login {
  constructor(@Inject(Http) http) {
    console.log('http', http);
  }
}
/********************/
@Inject(Http)
export class Login {
  constructor(http) {
    console.log('http', http);
  }
}
/********************/
export class Login {
  constructor(Http: http) {
    console.log('http', http);
  }
}
/********************/
export class Login {
  constructor(http = Http) {
    console.log('http', http);
  }
}
/********************/
export class Login {
  constructor(Http) {
    this.http = new Http()
    console.log('http', this.http);
  }
}
/********************/
export class Login {
  constructor(http = new Http()) {
    console.log('http', http);
  }
}
```

All but the first compiles. Others give me access to either the Http class or an http instance. But none works.

I tried to following the discussion referenced by Eric Martinez in his comment. Login.js now:

```
import {Component, Inject, View, CORE_DIRECTIVES, ViewEncapsulation} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {HTTP_BINDINGS, Http, BaseRequestOptions, RequestOptions, RequestMethods} from 'angular2/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'login'
})
@View({
  templateUrl: './components/login/login.html',
  styleUrls: ['components/login/login.css'],
  directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated,
  bindings: [Http]
})
export class Login {

  constructor(http) {
    this.http = http;
    console.log('http', http);
  }

  authenticate(usernameEl, passwordEl) {
    var username = usernameEl.value;
    var password = passwordEl.value;
    console.log('username', username, password);

    // this.http.get('/login');
  }
}

Login.parameters = [Http];
```

It compiles now but generates the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) NoBindingError {message: "No provider for Http!
>   (Login -> Http)", stack: "Error: DI Exception↵    at
>   NoBindingError.BaseExce…or._new
>   (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:7319:22)", keys: Array[2], injectors:
>   Array[2]}constructResolvingMessage: (keys)arguments: (...)caller:
>   (...)length: 1name: ""prototype: Object__proto__: ()context: (...)injectors: Array[2]0: Injector1: Injectorlength:
>   2__proto__: Array[0]keys: Array[2]message: "No provider for Http!
>   (Login -> Http)"stack: "Error: DI Exception↵    at
>   NoBindingError.BaseException [as constructor]
>   (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:8400:24)↵    at
>   NoBindingError.AbstractBindingError [as constructor]
>   (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:9066:17)↵    at new NoBindingError
>   (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:9102:17)↵    at Injector._throwOrNull
>   (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:7469:20)↵    at
>   Injector._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:7516:22)↵
>   at Injector._getByKey (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:7461:26)↵    at
>   Injector._getByDependency (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:7447:26)↵
>   at Injector._instantiate (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:7339:37)↵
>   at Injector._instantiateBinding
>   (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:7330:26)↵    at Injector._new
>   (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:7319:22)"**proto**: __

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4334) and [@brandonroberts comments](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4334#issuecomment-142676405)

Comment: @EricMartinez Thanks for the reference. I modified it to match my understanding of the discussion. Unfortunately, I'm getting an error.

Comment: Change this line `bindings: [Http]` to `bindings: [HTTP_BINDINGS]` and put it in `@Component` annotation and give it another try.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Since you have `@Decorators` enabled in Babel**

...I'll fine-tune this answer to work with your specific setup.

*1. You're missing [HTTP_PROVIDERS](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/HTTP_PROVIDERS-let.html])*

The HTTP_PROVIDERS constant includes a number of functions required to handle HTTP requests/responses.

```
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';    

@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  providers: [ HTTP_PROVIDERS ]
})
```

*2. You need to desugar the DI (Dependency Injection) syntax*

*As mentioned in [@alexpods' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33036779/290340).*

Remove the static typing

```
constructor(http) {
```

@Inject handles DI implicitly but is only supported in Angular2+Typescript. Since you're using Angular2+ES6 you need to attach a static getter parameter to your class to provide the ES6-specific equivalent.

```
static get parameters() {
    return [[Http]];
}
```

*3. You need to bind the Http instance to your class in the constructor*

By doing this, it will become accessible in your `authenticate()` method.

```
constructor(http) {
    this.http = http;
    console.log('http', this.http);
}
```

---

*...and the full implementation:*

```
import {Component, Inject, View, CORE_DIRECTIVES, ViewEncapsulation} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  // required for Http
  providers: [ HTTP_PROVIDERS ]
})
@View({
  templateUrl: './components/login/login.html',
  styleUrls: ['components/login/login.css'],
  directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated
})
export class Login {
  constructor(http) {
    // bind http to your class during construction
    //   so it's available to authenticate()
    this.http = http;
  }

  // Angular2 DI desugar'd
  static get parameters() {
    return [[Http]];
  }

  authenticate(username, password) {
    this.http.get('/login');
  }
}
```

*Aside: I know for a fact this works because I'm using it for the `<ng2-markdown>` component on [EvanPlaice.com.](https://github.com/evanplaice/evanplaice.com/blob/master/app/components/markdown/markdown.js)*

Answer (score 9):

How I've already answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33034930/how-to-use-angular2-dynamiccomponentloader-in-es6), If you write code in ES7, use static getter for `parameters` property to specify injections into `constructor` of your component. For example:

```
import { Http } from 'angular2/http';
// other imports ...

// component decorators ...
export class Login {

  static get parameters() {
    return [[Http]];
  }

  constructor(http) {
    this.http = http;
    console.log('http', http);
  }

  // other methods
}
```

I think it most concise method at this moment.

Remember there is no proposal to support parameter decorators in ES7 at this moment (for example [see this issue for Babel](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/1301)).

Comment: alexpds, thanks for the info and references. Unfortunately, works for bootstrapping app but not in component. It sill throws a NoBindingError. I also tried return both [HTTP] and HTTP_BINDINGS but still saw a NoBindingError. I noticed in the SO answer you referenced, the plunker has included traceur. I'm going to try to reproduce what I'm seeing in another plunger using only babel. Note I was able to get it to work using Eric Martinez' comment.

Comment: @alexpods despite parameter decorators only being a proposal, enabling `@Decorator` support in Babel/Traceur is trivial. +1 for the desugaring syntax, I'm pretty sure this is the answer that helped me initially tackle DI on my own site.

Comment: @EvanPlaice Parameter decorators haven't been proposed yet. (by parameter decorators I mean `constructor(@Inject(Http) http) {}`. `@Inject` is a parameter decorator). What we have for now are [class and property decorators](https://github.com/wycats/javascript-decorators/blob/master/README.md). Unfortunately my link to the babel issue doesn't work anymore. It had a very good discussion about decorators in babel.

Comment: @alexpods My mistake, what I *meant* to say is `@Class` decorators are currently supported. `@Property` decorators are a whole other animal. Each one implicitly provides a unique higher order functionality so there's generalizable approach to desugar them all via ES6.

Comment: @EvanPlaice How can i update the data my components are using from a shared service ?

Comment: @Synturas Create a method in your service that makes the HTTP request and returns an observable. Subscribe to the observable in your component. If you need to do synchronous updates across multiple observables, look up the difference between hot/cold observables.

Answer (score 0):

Method from the official [API Review](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/http/Http-class.html) works for me:

```
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
@Component({
  selector: 'http-app',
  viewProviders: [HTTP_PROVIDERS],
  templateUrl: 'people.html'
})
class PeopleComponent {
  constructor(http: Http) {
    http.get('people.json')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(people => this.people = people);
  }
}
```

Comment: What transpiler are you using? Do you have an option flag set or are you including any polyfills?

Answer (score 0):

With [babel-plugin-angular2-annotations](https://github.com/shuhei/babel-plugin-angular2-annotations), you can inject services with constructor parameter type annotations just like TypeScript.

Install babel plugins:

```
npm install -D babel-plugin-angular2-annotations babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy babel-plugin-transform-class-properties babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types babel-preset-es2015
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "angular2-annotations",
    "transform-decorators-legacy",
    "transform-class-properties",
    "transform-flow-strip-types"
  ],
  "presets": [
    "es2015"
  ]
}
```

and voila!

```
import {Component, View, CORE_DIRECTIVES, ViewEncapsulation} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'login'
})
@View({
  templateUrl: './components/login/login.html',
  styleUrls: ['components/login/login.css'],
  directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated
})
export class Login {
  constructor(http: Http) {
    console.log('http', http);
    this.http = http;
  }

  authenticate(username, password) {
    this.http.get('/login');
  }
}
```

Note that the type signature is used only for a hint for dependency injection and not used for type-checking.

Comment: For anyone else, I was banging my head against the wall because I had listed my babel plugins in the wrong order - make sure it's in the same order as here. (annotations first)