# Angular2 ES6/ES2015 Babel - Syntax error with Angular 2 @ symbol

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Babel CLI is giving me this error whilst running it in the terminal:

```
> Benjamins-MacBook-Pro:public Ben$ npm run build
    > 
    > > angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 build /Users/Ben/Development/whatwegrowangular2/public
    > > babel boot.js -d lib
    > 
    > SyntaxError: boot.js: Unexpected token (5:0)   3 |    4 | //
    > Annotation section
    > > 5 | @Component({
    >     | ^   6 |   selector: 'my-app',   7 |   template: '<h1>Hello {{ name }}</h1>'   8 | })
```

I am using ES6/ES2015, and Angular 2.

Visual studio code is my development environment.

Any Ideas on the issue? The error is on the "@" symbol just before component.

Package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run lite",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "build": "babel boot.js -d lib"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.6",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
    "zone.js": "0.5.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.3.17",
    "lite-server": "^1.3.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You need to enable ES7 decorator support**

Support for `@Class` decorators (ie the cause of your error) can be enabled the option flags.

```
$ babel --optional es7.decorators
```

Decorators are used extensively in Typescript to allow the language to mimic the characteristics of traditional statically typed OOP languages. `@Class` decorators act as a higher order factory function, `@Property` decorators allow the use of getters/setters in JS, etc.

Angular2 uses them extensively because it's written in Typescript. Despite that, decorators are only at the '[proposal](https://tc39.github.io/process-document/)' stage of possibly being included in the [future ES7 specification](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262).

*Source:*

- [Exploring Decorators - Medium](https://medium.com/google-developers/exploring-es7-decorators-76ecb65fb841#.j6fi9iv64)

*Related:*

- [How Can I Use Decorators Today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34461548/how-can-i-use-decorators-today)

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting a `command not found` error in the terminal for `babel`. I have babel installed but have never used it with a `babel` command in a terminal. I cause it to run by adding it to my package.json file and then I go to the terminal and type npm run build from the directory of my package.json file. Where should I type your answer into?

Comment: @user3935156 It looks like Babeljs has changed config since the article I linked was posted. You'll need to install the decorators plugin and enable it in the config. https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/

Comment: Cheers. I installed the decorator plugin got it configured and outputting a file. However the file it outputs is exactly the same as the input file. My browser console still complains about the import statement: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`. It is really a seperate issue so I will mark this as the answer. My new question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34560592/babel-outputting-exact-copy-of-angular2-file

Comment: @user3935156 You need an es6-module-loader polyfill to use import. System.js is probably your best bet.