# angular2 cannot read property 'validator' of undefined when use ngFormModel (ES6)

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I got some problem when use ngFormModel directive with form
it said "TypeError: Cannot read property 'validator' of undefined in form_one (I write this code from NG-BOOK 2 Tutorial but it's not work!)

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'
import {
  FORM_DIRECTIVES,
  FormBuilder,
  ControlGroup,
  Validators
} from 'angular2/common'

@Component({
  selector: 'demo-form-sku-builder',
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES],
  template: `
  <div class="ui raised segment">
    <h2 class="ui header">Demo Form: Sku with FormBuilder</h2>
    <form class="ui form"
      [ngFormModel]="myForm"
      (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm.value)">
      <div class="field">
        <label for="skuInput">SKU</label>
        <input type="text"
          id="skuInput"
          placeholder="SKU"
          [ngFormControl]="myForm.controls['sku']">
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="ui button">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  `
})
export class DemoFormSkuBuilder {

  contructor (formBuilder) {
      this.myForm = formBuilder.group({
        'sku': ['', Validators.required]
      })
  }

  onSubmit(value) {
    console.log("you submitted value: ", value);
  }
}
```

edited:  (@Thierry Templier)

```
contructor (formBuilder) {
    this.fb = formBuilder;
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      'sku': ['', Validators.required]
    })
  }

  static get parameters() {
    return [[FormBuilder]];
  }
```

my libraries:

```
import 'es6-shim';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-microtask'
import 'rxjs/Rx'
import 'es6-promise'
```

Comment: You didn't set `form_one` property in `DemoFormSkuBuilder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a form  control in your component:

```
import {FormBuilder} from 'angular2/common';

@Component({
  (...)
})
export class DemoFormSkuBuilder {
  contructor (private fb:FormBuilder) {
    this.form_one = this.fb.group({
      (...)
    });
  }
}
```

You could have a look at this article for more details in the section "Using existing controls":

- Implementing Angular2 forms beyond basics - http://restlet.com/blog/2016/02/11/implementing-angular2-forms-beyond-basics-part-1/

**Edit**

If you want to inject within ES6, you need to define a static getter parameter:

```
import {FormBuilder} from 'angular2/common';

@Component({
  (...)
})
export class DemoFormSkuBuilder {
  contructor (fb) {
    this.fb = fb;
    this.form_one = this.fb.group({
      (...)
    });
  }

  static get parameters() {
    return [[FormBuilder]];
  }
}
```

Here is a working plunkr describing this approach: https://plnkr.co/edit/ymSUUCvG5NFvmCGqzj2r?p=preview.

See this question:

- [How to Inject Angular2 Http service into es6/7 Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33026015/how-to-inject-angular2-http-service-into-es6-7-class)

Comment: but  I wrote on ES6, so it can define the type ?
I updated the original code

Comment: Yes you're right. If you only use ES6, there is something specific to do. See this question for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33026015/how-to-inject-angular2-http-service-into-es6-7-class.

Comment: Could you provide the JS files you included in the HTML main file and configuration to try to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Here is a working plunkr using this approach: https://plnkr.co/edit/ymSUUCvG5NFvmCGqzj2r?p=preview.