# Typescript: can't compile file with : notation in constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I'm following some examples of a Ionic (with Angular 2) app.
All classes' constructor have something like:

```
export class UserService {
    constructor(http: Http) {
        this.http = http;
    }
}
```

but the compiler outputs this error:

```
Unexpected token (14:17)
  12 |  }
  13 | 
> 14 |  constructor(http: Http)
at Parser.pp.raise (/home/cbenseler/dev/apps/expressoapp/node_modules/babylon/index.js:1425:13)
```

This is probably something wront with the setup of my app (which uses babel and webpack) but I can't find what is the problem.

The webpack.config.js file has this:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015'],
          plugins: ['transform-decorators-legacy']
        },
        include: path.resolve('app'),
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.resolve('node_modules/angular2'),
        loader: 'strip-sourcemap'
      }
    ],
    noParse: [
      /es6-shim/,
      /reflect-metadata/,
      /zone\.js(\/|\\)dist(\/|\\)zone-microtask/
    ]
  }
```

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Are you running Webpack on the output of a TypeScript compiler? Because if not, you'll need a loader to convert it to JavaScript - neither Babel or Webpack understand TypeScript by themselves.

Comment: Hmm, I really don't know. I'm following an Ionic starter projet which comes with all set up. I'm going to check this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would see one thing that could potentially miss:

- You forget to import the `Http` class, so the compiler couldn't resolve it:

  ```
  import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
  ```

**Edit**

If you use ES6 only (it seems to be the case), you can use type at parameter level. To inject in this case, you need to use such approach:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(http) {
    this.http = http;
  }

  static get parameters() {
    return [[Http]];
  }
}
```

See these links for more details:

- [angular2 cannot read property 'validator' of undefined when use ngFormModel (ES6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35556960/angular2-cannot-read-property-validator-of-undefined-when-use-ngformmodel-es6/35557047#35557047)
- https://medium.com/@euphocat/angular2-router-in-es6-7-and-dependency-injection-b96944c3ba2e#.qat3cl6b4

Comment: It's being imported, I have double check this. The problem is in the typescript syntax + babel transpile.

Comment: But Babel isn't TypeScript so you can't use types at parameter level. You need to create a static getter for `parameters`. I updated my answer...

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfect! I'll just take a look why the starter project from Ionic doesn't have this typescript support.